# Xeditable datepicker [Date format doesn't work properly with newer angular.js version .]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, x-editable

On the first instance of choosing the datepicker, the date is seen as "Wed May 02 1984 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" instead of 1984-05-02.

**HTML:**

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <a href="#" editable-bsdate="user.dob" e-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy">
      {{ (user.dob | date:"dd/MM/yyyy") || 'empty' }}
  </a>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "ui.bootstrap"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs2';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.user = {
    dob: new Date(1984, 4, 15)
  };
});
```

Found out the issue was with the angular version.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/23/) of example with the older version of angular.js and here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/11461/) with newer version of angularJS

Is this still an existing bug or has this been rectified?

Thanks